# Shell script to find powers of 2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a script that will read user input, check if the arguments are numbers and then check which ones are powers of 2.

```
#!/bin/bash

n='^[0-9]+$'
i=0
a=2
c=$((&a**&n))

for i in "$@"; do
  if [[ $i =~ $n ]]; then
    if [[ $i == $c ]]; then
      echo " $i is a power of 2 "
    fi
  fi
  ((i++))       
done
```

But i get this error: >a**&n: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "&n")

Comment: For a first overview please paste your script there: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I really wish people would assign shell programming tasks that actually *resemble* real-world uses of shell.

Comment: The use of the variable `c` doesn't make sense. The formula it's set to seems to be 2 raised to the power of a regular expression (which is meaningless), and I'm not sure what the `&` characters are supposed to be. Also, when you use it, you're comparing it as a string (or possibly wildcard pattern) against a number, which doesn't make sense either. BTW, is this related to [this question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886069/test-if-argument-is-power-of-2-and-show-the-sum-of-the-arguments-using-bash)?

Comment: @RiderOfLightning : As the error message says: `&n` does not make sense. There is no unary arithmetic operator named `&`. What did you want to express by it?

Comment: Ughh yes that `&` was supposed to be a `$` , it was a stupid mistake. And I'msuper  new to shell scripting and I didn't know that you can't raise 2 to the power of a regex thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

n='^[0-9]+$'

for i in "$@"; do
  if [[ $i =~ $n ]]; then
      if [[ $((i & (i-1))) == 0 ]]; then
      echo " $i is a power of 2 "
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: bash regex are very expensive! Have a look at [my version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58901497/1765658), approx 2x quicker!